# Highest possible right hand ATK weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-2

There are many weapons. I want to find the highest possible RightHand1 ATK weapon. So far, the dark sacret chime hammer +5 is my record.

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/4aa9c5fa8c65ce37c89d3d5825af164f.png]

This is without ring buffs. 
Can someone help me find the highest possible right hand ATK weapon?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you want to add scaling into your definition of highest Attack Rating. The Raw [Malformed Skull](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Malformed+Skull) +10 clocks in with a whopping 563 AR with no scaling. From personal experience, when power stancing and buffed with crystal magic weapon, raw malformed skull's L2 will deal nearly 1200 damage on Giant Lord regardless of which ng you're currently playing. On the other hand, the [Great Club](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Great+Club) +10 does 567 AR at 50 strength making it a strong contender to the malformed skull at higher levels. Beyond that it's just personal preference!

Comment: It's all dependent on your stats so if you want a specific answer for a specific build, then provide specific stats. Otherwise do the work yourself

Comment: I feel as if people look for excuses to not answer the question, or to try to do a half ass reply for some kind of personal gain. You know the value "RightHand1ATK", yea What is the highest possible number there in what circumstance. How is that not specific enough?

Comment: Well since weapons scale, its highly dependent on your stats. A weapon could hit really hard at 99 str/dex/int/faith but not so much at 20. The chime hammer's base stats compared to other weapons are meh but it scales well at higher levels. We also need to factor in infusions as well. Are you using a mundane build?  A dex build? Some weapons will have a much higher AR with a proper build. The kind of answer you're looking for isn't suited for this site seeing that there are hundreds of possibilities for building your character in Dark Souls 2. Supply specifics and I can give a better answer.

Comment: I want to know highest AR with scaling and items possible. Is it possible to have 99 stats? yes or no? obviously yes, so yes, since it is possible to have all 99 stats then the answer "depends on your stats" is dumb and invalid.

Comment: @user2656801 Seeing as you never specified, then no, it isn't. With these questions it is *entirely* up to the stats you're using. Every Dark Souls 2 stat build question *requires* at least an assumed stat level from the OP (in this case, you).

Comment: OP is asking for the maximum number, so what we have to do is 1) Assume that he has 99 stats in everything 2) Consider the stats for max tempered weapons 3) Consider the number for every possible element 4) Assume that he'll take any type of weapon, be it sword, greatsword, bow or others. I don't see how he needs to be more specific. The fact that he didn't specify any limitation is the specification itself

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but yesterday I powerstanced two lightning infused giant warrior clubs at 99 strength and 66 faith.

I was doing about 2.2k damage to giant lord in New Game Plus 99 and I killed him in under a minute.